# Should Builder calculate parameter values

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

Let's say I have following class and a builder for it:

```
public class A(){
    private B b;
    private C c;

    private A(Builder builder) {
       this.b = builder.b;
       this.c = bulder.c;
    }

    public static class Builder() {
       private B b;
       private C c;

       public Builder setB(B b){
           this.b = b;
           return this;
       }

       public Builder setC(C c){
           this.C = c;
           return this;
       }

       public A build(){
          return new A(this);
       }
    }
}
```

Now let's say that b and c need to be calculated somehow (for example, based on list of D). May question is:

Where to put filling parameters b and c based on some calculation, that is, should I place calculation in A, in builder, or somewhere else?

Comment: This seems like a strange use of the builder to me. Why does you `A` take a builder? If `b` and `c` are not optional, then `A` should require them through the constructor. The builder should be used to set the optional (or configurable) properties of `A`, I wouldn't pass the builder to `A`.

Comment: This is not the full class, it is just an example. There are more parameters that are optional, hence the builder. I found an implementation like this like an example somewhere, constructor A is private, so this way I'm just avoiding having a large constructor which would have the same body as in this case, except that parameters would be passed directly instead of builder. If I pass parameters b and c through constructor wouldn't I break the builder concept? Where would I put the other parameters which are optional?

Comment: If `b` and `c` are not optional then the builder does not give any advantage, in fact it creates a problem, as what If I don't call `setB`? If they are optional then just create an `A` (in the constructor of the builder) and set them on `A` when the builder method is called.

Comment: For a discussion on mandatory builder methods, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126276/how-to-mark-a-method-obligatory

Answer (score 0):

I would choose the option based on whether or not the list `D` can be chnaged once `A` knows about it. If it can then the properties need to be able to be recalculated, so should do the calculation themselves. If `D` is a fixed list once given to `A` then the properties could be 'cached' and calculated up front